# Can I integrate Jest with Webdriverio for cross-browser testing

Tags: jestjs, integration, webdriver-io

Can I integrate Jest with Webdriverio for cross-browser testing?
Because I not found any information about that in the stack overflow. Only one GitHub post say about that: https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/2052
On the official site of the Jest and Webdriver io says nothing about the integration of those frameworks.
Can someone any information about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand based on their integration with cucumber, it may not be so easy to do this. I have worked on similar framework before and I feel webdriver has to make some changes in their core so that it can be integrated with other test runners and frameworks.

The maintainer have mentioned his observation in the issue shared under [this](https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/2052#issuecomment-459979632) comment.

Comment: Thank you for answer.